GTFS Realtime Data: Is it only in bulk? I want to look up specific transit information
When I request GTFS realtime data from my local Transit system, it gives me all data it has at once...
This is a ton of data that I don't need. There's so much data that my console runs out of space to scroll.
For example, if I want to keep track of where a bus currently is via it's latitude and longitude, I need to constantly request it. This is going to be a huge amount of resources since it's downloading everything all at once every time!
Is GTFS only meant to be retrieved in bulk or is there a way to retrieve specific data? Here is my current node.js code to get realtime bus position data:
    const apiUrl = `https://gtfsapi.translink.ca/v3/gtfsposition?apikey=${apiKey}`;

    axios.get(apiUrl, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).then(response => {
        // Parse the GTFS Realtime data
        const buffer = response.data;
        const message = FeedMessage.decode(buffer);
        const data = FeedMessage.toObject(message, {
            longs: String,
            enums: String,
            bytes: String,
        });

        // Process the data as needed
        log.debug("data:", data);
    }).catch(error => {
        log.error('Error fetching translink trip data:', error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error });
    });

